# How to include an iframe into a Facebook page/post?

Tags: html, facebook, web

Are there ways to show an iframe of a website on a Facebook page or in a post?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs - but it’s been restricted to pages with at least 2k likes a while back.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so I am answering it. You can use facebook's post as an iframe in the website but can't do the opposite in facebook's post, you cannot use the code in the posts as it doesn't allow code. Therefore, it won't work.